# CSS mobile change float order

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the float order for floated columns on mobile device. Have tried changing the float to none and clearing both but it's not working. Am using Sass which is compiling the code fine. Can't see where I'm going wrong. Thanks

I need the mobile layout to be the following:

text
image
text
image

HTML:

```
<div class="half">
        <div class="inner-right text-block">
            <h3 class="black">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x450/000/fff" role="img" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- One half half -->
    <div class="half">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x450/000/fff" role="img" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <div class="inner-right text-block">
            <h3 class="black">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.half {
        width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
        @media (max-width: $mobile) {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
            clear: both;
        }
    }
.left {
float: left;
}
.right: {
 float:right;
}
```

Fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/jxhdyjks/1/

Comment: `$mobile` isn't a valid CSS output. It's a SASS variable name. Are you sure this is the result of your SASS compilation? :)

Comment: This isn't the result, this is in the sass file. $variable outputs 667px

Comment: It works for me. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/jxhdyjks/3/

Comment: By the way, you don't need to set display to `inline-block` whenever you `float` the elements. To get divs to be next to each other, either go with `float` OR `display: inline-block`. Not both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tw0akjjj/

I changed two things:

1.) Put the media query below the other rules, since the left and right classes will override it otherwise

2.) Added a rule for the images (`.half img`) to have 100% width inside their (responsive, changing) container

ADDITION/EDIT:

Please note the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tw0akjjj/2/

I turned around the order of the DIVs for the second row in the HTML and set the DIVs in that second row to `float: right`.

In the desktop version this becomes

```
text image
image text
```

in the mobile version:

```
text
image
text
image
```

Comment: I need the layout on mobile to be text image text image, not text image image text

Comment: Nice one @johannes - thanks, didn't think to float the second row right on mobile devices.